# C# WinForm How to set date format in datatable?

Tags: c#, datetime, datatable, datagridview, tostring

I am new to C# and I am working on a project.

I got a column that contained datetime from Excel, I am going to input the data into DataGridView via datatable.

What I have in my Excel, ex: 2022/05/29

I want to change to specific format like: 20220529

I think it should be really simple but I just cannot get it right.

What I have tried is like below:

```
int col = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= 23; i++) 
{
    DataRow row = dt_d.NewRow();
    dt_d.BeginLoadData();
    for (int j = 2; j <= 21; j++)
    {
        if (excelRange.Cells[j, i].Value != null)
        {
            if (i == 3)
            {
                DateTime date1 = (DateTime)excelRange.Cells[j, 3];
                date1.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
            }
            if (i == 5)
            {
                DateTime date2 = (DateTime)excelRange.Cells[j, 5];
                date2.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
            }
            if (i == 22)
            {
                DateTime date3 = (DateTime)excelRange.Cells[j, 22];
                date3.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
            }
            row[col] = excelRange.Cells[i, j].Value.ToString();
        }
    }
    col++;
    dt_d.EndLoadData();
    dt_d.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

When I execute it, it give me a hresult: 0x800a03ec Exception...
I also tried code like these

```
dataGridView1.Columns[3].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "yyyyMMdd";
dataGridView1.Columns[5].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "yyyyMMdd";
dataGridView1.Columns[22].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "yyyyMMdd";
```

But the result doesn't change at all.
Can anyone give me some suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: Change `row[col] = excelRange.Cells[i, j].Value.ToString();` to `row[col] = excelRange.Cells[j, i].Value.ToString();`

Comment: If I remember correctly excell cells cannot be accessed with zero-based indices. `for (int i = 0;` seems the reason of your exception.

Comment: @DotNetDeveloper Thank you for answering me. I just modified the code as you say, and I got a message that said "Unable to cast object of type 'System._ComObject' to type 'System.Time'" So I changed the code to `DateTime date1 = Convert.ToDateTime(excelRange.Cells[j, 3].Value);` but it said it cannot recognize valid DateTime.

Comment: What Excel library are you using? And “why” do you want to “format” the `DateTime` object IN the `DataTable`? Some of the posted code looks quite odd and I have to ask what the lines of code like… `dateX.ToString("yyyyMMdd");` do … ? … This code accomplishes absolutely nothing. The code will “return” a `string` but the code is ignoring this and does nothing with the retuned value. So the code has no affect whatsoever, can you clarify what you are trying to do with this code?